# php sql while very slow

Tags: php, performance

i have the following code, which is working for me as it should, except for the fact that it takes a long time, before the queries are done? how can i make it faster? with 2 records it takes about 1 to 2 minutes it seems.

```
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM preordertablet1"; 
$result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()); 
$count = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
//$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Gegevens niet kunnen ophalen uit preorder tabel. Foutmelding: ".mysql_error());
$c=0;
while ($c<=$count) 
    {
    $query="SELECT * FROM preordertablet1 WHERE ID = '$c'";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("gegevens niet geladen uit de preordertabel, fout: ".mysql_error());
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
        $ID1=$ID1+1;
        $c++;
        $naam=$row['naam'];
        $Postcodehuisnummer=$row['Postcodehuisnummer'];
        $datum=$row['datum'];
        $dagen=$row['dagen'];
        $productid=$row['productid'];
        $subid=$row['subid'];
        //$ID2=$ID1;
        //gegevens in database plaatsen
        $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO huur (ID, ID2, status, naam, Postcodehuisnummer, datum, dagen, productid, subid) VALUES ('$ID1', '$ID2', '1', '$naam', '$postcodehuisnummer', '$huurdatum', '$aantaldagen', '$productid', '$subid')") or die ("Fout: ".mysql_error());
        echo 'preorder fiets toegevoegd met ID2: ', $ID2,'<br>';
        //$ID1=$ID1+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Define "long time". How many records do you have?

Comment: just 2 records, takes about 1 or 2 minutes it seems?

Comment: Is it perhaps just your database end that is causing the problem? If you perform the same query in the mysql browser what sort of performance do you get?

Comment: @user2133342 Your page doesn't make sense. You're getting the count of all items from a table, then for each number from 0 to that count, you're getting that individual row. Why not just make your first query: `SELECT * FROM preordertablet1`? Avoid the nested loop.

Comment: i tried before, but from two records, it only returned 1. but i will try again

Comment: As `Colin Morelli` already mentioned the fact but also at the end of your loop `where id=2` will make an error because `count=2` is `0 and 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume this is all of the code you're running then the first query is pretty much useless since you want to parse through all the rows no matter how many. So you can skip the first three lines all together.

Then there's the $c variable, unless you need to know how many rows you parse through this can be scrapped as well.

Then there's the query inside the first loop, the "WHERE ID = '$c'" part is most likely what causes you to only get one inserted row. If the ID column is an auto_increment primary key the first inserted row will have a value of at least 1 but the first check you do is for an ID = 0 which returns nothing. The last iteration of a table with two rows will therefore be for an ID of 1 but there's no guarantee that there's any row with that ID but in your case there is one and I'm guessing that this is the row you're seeing in your result.

I'm not going to try to suggest corrections for the second while loop without a bit more information about the columns such as ID1 and ID2. Maybe you could post the table definitions (the create table structure) and explain a bit further?

As others have said, don't use mysql_ functions, these can disappear from PHP anytime as they are deprecated.

All of this is of course based on guessing about the tables since you haven't posted the table layout or what it is you're trying to achieve.

To get you a bit on the road here's a simpler code snippet, it's not complete but should give you the idea, [read about PDO here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
$pdo = new PDO(<insert your connection information here>);
$selectStmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM preordertablet1');
$insertStmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO huur
    (ID, ID2, status, naam, Postcodehuisnummer, datum, dagen, productid, subid)
  VALUES
    (:ID1, :ID2, '1', :naam, :postcode, :datum, :dagen, :productid, :subid)");
$ID1 = 0; // Or whatever starting value you're working from.

while ($row = $selectStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ID1++;
    $values = array("ID1" => $ID1, "ID2" => NULL, "naam" => $row['naam'], etc...
    $insertStmt->execute($values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$result` variable is being re-used for the insert operation. Then the `$result` value is tested in the while loop.

```
 $result_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO huur etc etc")
```

Comment: its not a large table for now. just testing, and currently consists of only 2 records

Comment: Should the loop condition be $c < $count ?

Comment: i just wanted to get all row entries from the table, but when i use SELECT * FROM preordertablet1 it only returns 1 entry, and not both entries. it should return both (with ID 0 and 1)

Comment: can you check the value of $c for each loop iteration?

Comment: i placed an echo $c in the while loop, but it does not show anything. the records are put in the database as it should, but i takes 1 min, and gives the following errors:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given .   and also Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Comment: That indicates the loop is not terminating. Have you tried changing the loop condition to $c < $count?

Comment: Finally! I think this answer is the solution.

Comment: too bad, that does not matter too. still slow

Comment: If the ID column is a primary key then the reuse of the $result variable will never be an issue since the inner while loop will only ever execute once per outer loop (only one row can have the requested ID).